# Define type alias between template and class declaration in order to inherent from it

Tags: c++, templates, alias

I have a class template which uses some type alias through its implementation, and also inherits from the same type:

```
template<typename TLongTypename, 
         typename TAnotherLongTypename, 
         typename THeyLookAnotherTypename>
class A : SomeLongClassName<TLongTypename, 
                           TAnotherLongTypename,
                           THeyLookAnotherTypename>
{
    using Meow = SomeLongClassName<TLongTypename, 
                                   TAnotherLongTypename, 
                                   THeyLookAnotherTypename>;
    
    // ... (using Meow a lot)
};
```

Naturally I want to inherit from the type alias `Meow` and not from the long name. Is there any nice way to do that, hopefully such that `Meow` will be defined inside the template scope but before the class scope?

Comment: You can define Meow first but that only gets rid of `SomeLongClassName` and none of the template arguments.

Comment: `Meow` only has meaning within some specific _instantiation_ of class template `A`, so, tl;dr; no.

Comment: Does it help if you think _"class template_" instead? That is, not a class, but a template that can be used to instantiate one.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow No need, with the code as posted (if you fix the typos) you can do, for example: `class B : public A<int, float, double>::Meow { };`

Comment: You sill have `int, float, double` in there. That's what I mend with not getting rid of the template arguments, just in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare the type alias `Meow` as a default template parameter, directly in the template parameter list, which means you only have to spell it out once:

```
template<typename TLongTypename, 
         typename TAnotherLongTypename, 
         typename THeyLookAnotherTypename,
         // declare Meow once here 
         typename Meow = SomeLongClassName<TLongTypename, 
                                           TAnotherLongTypename,
                                           THeyLookAnotherTypename>>
class A : Meow   // inherit
{
    Meow X;   // use
};
```